# Firefox inspector sees elements with IDs that javascript console cannot find

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, web-applications

Trying to automate some tasks on a private web application. When I use a right click > Inspect Element on a form field for example, I am shown the Inspector panel, and the HTML element is shown, with its id right there. Problem is, if I run a

```
document.getElementById('theId_shown_on_the_inspector');
```

on the console, I just get *null* back. This web application relies on Java by the way.

Is there anything you can think off that may throw some light on this weird behavior? Basically I need to be able to automatically populate some fields and click on some buttons, but I cant if I am not able to detect them.

Comment: is there an iframe in play? What happens if you right click the element in inspector and choose "Use in console"

Comment: Yes I do see an iframe, if I hover the cursor over it while on the Inspector panel, everything on the page is highlighted except for the navigation bar on top. So everything I want to manipulate seems to be inside it. If I right click elements on the Inspector panel > Use in console, I see the string "temp#" in the console input field, where # is a number like temp0, temp1, temp2 and it increases each time I repeat the process even if clicking on the same element. But pushing Enter on the console returns an empty object.

Comment: in developer tools, you can select which "frame" is in the console context - it looks like a box with two boxes in it somewhere top right of console window

Comment: wow! that worked, I selected another iframe and was able to select it through getElementById. Now, how would I go about choosing the correct iframe in my script? I am using GreaseMonkey.

Comment: the greasemonkey script would have to load in the context of iframe to work in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

As shared by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x), the page has iframes loading content from other URLs. Since I was working with GreaseMonkey, I did not include these URLs in the list of @includes, and using the Firefox console was not working either because you have to select and load those iframes into context (again as indicated by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)).

Firefox provides enough details about the iframe URLs which to include in the GreaseMonkey script.